# Join two dataframes median (IQR)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

Let's assume two dataframes of medians and interquartile ranges

```
medians = pd.DataFrame({"Median A" : [16, 14, 11], "Median B" : [9, 8, 5]})
iqrs = pd.DataFrame({"IQR A" : [5, 3, 4], "IQR B" : [2, 2, 4]})
```

What I'd like to to is to join these two dataframes in the way that in cell there is Median (IQR), so:

```
    Value A     Value B
0    16 (5)      9 (2)
1    14 (3)      8 (2)
2    11 (4)      5 (4)
```

I guess I need to start with converting both dataframes to type `str`, and apply `.join()`, but whatever I do it simply doesn't work.

Comment: `medians['Median A'].astype(str) + ' (' + iqrs['IQR A'].astype(str) + ')'`?

Comment: @Corralien Sure, but if there are many columns I'd have to iterate over them and I wonder whether there is a faster solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
medians = medians.astype(str)
iqrs = iqrs.map(lambda x: f' ({x})')

medians.add(iqrs.values)
```

Output:

```
  Median A Median B
0   16 (5)    9 (2)
1   14 (3)    8 (2)
2   11 (4)    5 (4)
```

Comment: I liked it with numpy!

Comment: Thanks, @Corralien! I had tried just `medians.astype(str) + iqrs.map(lambda x: f' ({x})')`, but got only `NaN`. So, we have to first assign the dataframes. Maybe, `pandas`, in the first approach, tries to convert the elements of the dataframes back to numeric.

Comment: `medians.astype(str) + iqrs.map(lambda x: f' ({x})').values` works for me

Comment: No, @Corralien, that does not work: The result is all `NaN`. Try it out!

Comment: I appended `.values` (or `.to_numpy()`) and it works perfectly (but it does not rename the columns ;-))

Comment: Yeah!, @Corralien: With `.values`, it works!

Answer (score 3):

Simple way for 2 columns:

```
va = medians['Median A'].astype(str) + ' (' + iqrs['IQR A'].astype(str) + ')'
vb = medians['Median B'].astype(str) + ' (' + iqrs['IQR B'].astype(str) + ')'
values = pd.DataFrame({'Value A': va, 'Value B': vb})
```

Output:

```
>>> values
  Value A Value B
0  16 (5)   9 (2)
1  14 (3)   8 (2)
2  11 (4)   5 (4)
```

If you have multiple columns, you can use `zip` and a comprehension to do that:

```
vals = {f'Value {m.split()[-1]}': medians[m].astype(str) + ' (' + iqrs[i].astype(str) + ')'
            for m, i in zip(medians, iqrs)}
values = pd.concat(vals, axis=1)
```

Another (over complicated?) way:

```
values = (pd.concat([medians, iqrs], axis=1).astype(str).T
            .groupby(lambda x: x.split()[-1])
            .agg(lambda x: x.iloc[0] + ' (' + x.iloc[1] + ')')
            .T.add_prefix('Value '))
```

Finally:

```
values = (medians.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('Median', 'Value')).astype(str) 
          + ' (' + iqrs.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('IQR', 'Value')).astype(str) + ')')
```